# How to generate a build in .bin format using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Am using Jenkins 1.566 on Windows and Java 1.7.0. Whenever I try to create a build, it's creating as a folder with sub files that are in `.xml` format. Is there any way to create the output in `.bin` format. I am using SVN for getting the source code of the project.

Comment: Could you add a little more details? I don't understand what your problem is. Why do you want to create `.bin` files and what should they contain?

Comment: Am planning to integrate Jenkins with our automation tool.For regression testing,I have to create nightly/weekly builds using our code. The .bin extension files only supported with our device.So is there any possibility to create .bin output files with the use of Jenkins instead of .xml file format.

Comment: Still, what do you expect the content of those `.bin` files?

Comment: Generally, you'd generate the `.bin` files exactly the same way under Jenkins, as you'd generate them from command line. If you can't generate them from command line, solve that first without worrying about Jenkins. If you can do it from command line but not from Jenkins, examine the Jenkins build output to see what is different from when you do it from command line.